# Why is my anchor href path, appending to the URL?

Tags: html, anchor

I'm utterly baffled by the following situation I find myself in and truthfully, I have no idea why the following is occurring or how to solve the issue.

**Here's what's happening;**

I have the following anchor;

```
<a href=”https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms”
   rel="nofollow"
   target="_blank">
   Terms
</a>
```

If the user clicks this anchor it results in the following URL:
`https://www.example.com/contact/"https:/policies.google.com/terms`

Naturally I was expecting the following URL to be loaded;
`https://policies.google.com/terms`

At first I thought it might be a syntax error, somewhere, so pulled the anchors and checked the code. I can't see any errors anywhere. From there, I tested other links in the page. (All are working fine.) So I thought 'well if they are working, maybe it was a typo in the code?', I rewrote the anchors and the same issue still occurs (*strange*).

So my second thought was the URL has to be weird somehow, so I used a couple of substitutes,
`www.google.com`, `www.youtube.com`, and `www.facebook.com`. All URLs resulted in the same result. Is the target `href=""` simply being appended to the URL?

I'm not doing anything fancy with my URLs, or JavaScript so why is this occurring? Has anyone ever encountered this? Or maybe a better question would be: How would one debug something like this?

Comment: can you share the full source code if possible. probably there is some unclosed quote

Comment: Sure here's the paste bin. https://pastebin.com/xibMZJD6

Comment: How did the non-standard quotes get there? Copy-pasting from a web page?

Comment: If memory serves this code was written from scratch so not likely. I do often. pull code and paste it into Apple Notes while debugging other things. It's possible they got in somewhere there. Maybe part of autocorrect? I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used incorrect double quotation marks. Take a look very closely at the HTML tags below:

```html
<p class="text-muted">We'll get back to you within 1-2 business days.</p>
<p class="small text-muted">(This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the <br>Google
<a href=”https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy” rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> and
<a href=”https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms” rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a> apply.)</p>
```

The quote used in `p` tag is `"` and it is different with the one used in the `a` tag, which is `”`.

You need to replace it with `"`.

```html
<p class="text-muted">We'll get back to you within 1-2 business days.</p>
<p class="small text-muted">(This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the <br>Google
<a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> and
<a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a> apply.)</p>
```

Comment: You either have some crazy eyesight or your using a tool I'd love to know the name of.... xD Thanks bro. you're a legend. +1